# How are file paths mapped to subdirectories in .dir-locals.el?

Tags: directory-local-variables

I like the idea of `.dir-locals.el`.  I have my own `.dir-locals.el` file in my home directory that should set all the variables for directories/files that I open unless there is `.dir-locals.el` closer to the directory I open the file in.  However, even though the file is recognized, directory variables for subdirectories are not applied to opened files.

This is my `~/.dir-locals.el`:

```lisp
(("dev/school" .
  ((indent-tabs-mode . nil)
   (c-basic-offset . 4)))
 ("dev/test" .
  ((indent-tabs-mode . nil)
   (c-basic-offset . 4)))
 (c-mode .
  ((c-file-style . "linux")
   (c-basic-offset . 8))))
```

When I open file `~/dev/test/test.c` the variable `indent-tabs-mode` is set to `t` and `c-basic-offset` is `8`.

`(describe-variable 'c-basic-offset)` in that file tells me it is set to `8` from `~/.dir-locals.el`.

`(describe-variable 'indent-tabs-mode)` in that file says it's value (`t`) is just in its default state.

Can I somehow achieve the desired behaviour?  What am I doing wrong?  How are file paths mapped to subdirectories in `~/.dir-locals.el`?

#### Edit:

As [Jonathan suggested](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12777/how-are-file-paths-mapped-to-subdirectories-in-dir-locals-el/12778#12778), I also tried:

```lisp
(;; dev/school subdir
 ("dev/school" .
  ;; dev/school specification for all modes
  (nil . ((indent-tabs-mode . nil)
          (c-basic-offset . 4)))))
```

and even what `add-dir-local-variable` added:

```lisp
(("dev/school"
  (indent-tabs-mode)
  (c-basic-offset . 4)))
```

Unfortunately, none of those work either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on the documentation in the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html), you are missing a portion of the subdir specification.

#### Sample .dir-locals.el

From the manual with comments for emphasis/clarification

```
(;; Dir settings
 (nil . ((indent-tabs-mode . t)
         (fill-column . 80)))
 (c-mode . ((c-file-style . "BSD")
            (subdirs . nil)))
 ;; Subdir specification
 ("src/imported" .
  ;; Subdir settings
  ((nil . ((change-log-default-name
            . "ChangeLog.local"))))))
```

#### Corrected .dir-locals.el

This is based on the assumption that you want the `subdir` specifications to apply to all modes.  If you only want them to apply to `c-mode` replace `nil` with `c-mode` in the mode-specification.

```
(;; dev/school subdir
 ("dev/school" .
  ;; dev/school specification for all modes
  ((nil . ((indent-tabs-mode . nil)
           (c-basic-offset . 4)))))
 ;; dev/test subdir
 ("dev/test" .
  ;; dev/test specification for all modes
  ((nil . ((indent-tabs-mode . nil)
           (c-basic-offset . 4)))))
 ;; c-mode specification for dir + subdirs
 (c-mode .
  ((c-file-style . "linux")
   (c-basic-offset . 8))))
```

Comment: I misunderstood that example in the documentaiton, thank you for clarifying that. However, I tried your version (copy-paste) and it still behaves the same way. Even with 'emacs -Q'. Suggestions for debugging are welcomed, too.

Comment: I also tried using `add-dir-local-variable` and it was added to `~/.dir-locals.el` with even shorter syntax than I used in the question: `("dev/test" (indent-tabs-mode))`. Still doesn't work, though.

Comment: I think my version was missing some parens, I've added them in (looking it over compared to the sample and there should have been extra ones around the subdir specs `("dev/test" . ((spec1 ...) (spec2 ...) ...))`

Comment: Yes, that works! The only problem now is that the mode variables take precedence over the directory ones, but since they are only related to c-mode I can set them with setq-default during init. Thank you very much.

Comment: That's strange.  I did a test today using `((org-mode . ((org-indent-mode . t))) ("subdir" . ((nil . ((org-indent-mode . nil))))` and it worked properly (prompted to set local var to nil).  Maybe try putting the root ones above the sub-dir specifications within the list, it's possible it sets it to the last value found.

Comment: Yes, that was it. I originally started with that sequence, but I changed it a lot in order to find the problem before asking here.